# Unable to select element in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code in Jquery -:

```
function setCaretPos(element) {
    element.focus(); 

    if(typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" && typeof document.createRange 
        != "undefined")
    {
        var range = document.createRange(); 
    referenceNode = element.getElementsByClassName("prettyTag")[0].nextSibling; 
        range.selectNode(referenceNode); range.collapse(true); 

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges(); sel.addRange(range);
    }
```

Function `setCaretPos` works when I do this -:
 `setCaretPos(document.getElementById("editor"));`
 but doesn't work when I do this -:
 
`var element = $("#editor"); setCaretPos(element)`;

I can only opt for the latter. How do i correct up the latter one. Thanks.. :)

Comment: check the console for errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('#editor')` is a jQuery object, yet your javascript expects a DOM object. jQuery objects are *not* the same as DOM objects.

Try `$('#editor').get(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var element = $("#editor")[0]; setCaretPos(element);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try point to DOMNode from JQuery Element:

```
var element = $("#editor"); setCaretPos(element[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because setCaretPos() expects a DOM element, not a jQuery object:

```
setCaretPos(element.get(0));
```

See also: [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)